# SectionedAdapter passing more then one string

Tags: android, adapter, android-adapter

in the adapter I have something like this

```
protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index, 
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

and in the caption variable I have one string. This string is passed along the adapter

```
adapter.addSection("the string", myadapter);
```

How can I pass more than one String? For example I have String A and String B, how can I pass them to the adapter and how can I read them latter on?
I need something like this

```
adapter.addsection(a, b, myadapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid :), the solution was easy instead to pass string I just passed array of strings...

My problem was that I didn't know that I can change the method definition...